# Trying to display different types of charts using select/option tag

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, chart.js

```js
// Vancouver Population
var ctx = document.getElementById("lineChart");
var lineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type:'line',
    data: {
        labels: ["2000", "2005", "2010", "2015", "2018"],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'Vancouver Population Data',    
            data: [195000,2093000,2278000,2485000,2597000],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255,99,132,1)'
            ],
            backgroundColor:['rgba(255,200,200,0.3)'],
            borderWidth: 1,
            //borderDash:([3]),
            pointBackgroundColor:"red",
            pointBorderColor: "rgba(250,10,10,0.1)",
            pointBorderWidth:"10",
            pointStyle:"rectRounded",
            pointHoverBackgroundColor:"rgba(255,0,0,0.5)",
            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,255,100,0.7)",
            pointHoverRadius:"10",
            //showLine:false,
            //steppedLine:"false"
        }]
    },
    options: {
        title:{
            display:true,
            text:"Populations in Vancouver",
            fontSize:20,
            fontColor:"rgba(20,20,20,1)"
        },
        legend:{
            display:false,
            position:'right',
            labels:{
                fontColor:'#000'
        },
        },
        elements:{
            line:{
                tension:0, //disables bezier curves
            }
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes:[{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true,
                    callback: function(value,index,values){
                    return value + " people"
                }
                }   
                           
            }]
        },
        /*animation: {
        duration:0, // general animation time
    },*/
    hover:{
        animationDuration:0, // duration of animations when hovering an item
    },
        responsiveAnimationDuration:0, // animation duration after a resize
    }
});

// Vancouver Precipitation

var ctx = document.getElementById("barChart");
var BarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type:'bar',
    data: {
        labels:["May 2017", "June 2017", "July 2017", "Aug 2017","Sep 2017","Oct 2017","Nov 2017","Dec 2017","Jan 2018","Feb 2018","Mar 2018","Apr 2018","May 2018"],
        datasets:[{
               label:"Precipitation Data",
                data:[102.2,46.4,1.8,5.0,29.4,114.8,197.0,170.6,249.4,105.8,111.8,134.8,1.4],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,0.5)',
                    'rgba(155,130,32,0.5)',
                    'rgba(105,9,132,0.5)',
                    'rgba(15,130,202,0.5)',
                    'rgba(15,250,252,0.5)',
                    'rgba(205,100,32,0.5)',
                    'rgba(0,205,0,0.5)',
                    'rgba(55,15,52,0.5)',
                    'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)',
                    'rgba(25,59,52,0.5)',
                    'rgba(0,100,55,0.5)',
                    'rgba(200,111,199,0.5)',
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                    'rgba(155,130,32,1)',
                    'rgba(105,9,132,1)',
                    'rgba(15,130,202,1)',
                    'rgba(15,250,252,1)',
                    'rgba(205,100,32,0.5)',
                    'rgba(0,205,0,1)',
                    'rgba(55,15,52,1)',
                    'rgba(255,0,0,1)',
                    'rgba(25,59,52,1)',
                    'rgba(0,100,55,1)',
                    'rgba(200,111,199,1)',
                ],
                borderWidth:"1",
                pointHoverBackgroundColor:"#fff",
                hoverBorderColor:"#fff",
             }]
    },
    options: {
        title:{
            display:true,
            text:"Vancouver Precipitation",
            fontSize:20,
            fontColor:"rgba(10,0,20,0.9)"
        },
            legend:{
            display:false,
            position:'right',
            labels:{
                fontColor:'#000'
        }
            },
        scales:{
            yAxes:[{
                ticks:{
                    beginAtZero:true,
                    callback: function(value,index,values){
                    return value + " mm"
                }
                }
            }]
        }
    },
});

// Ethnicity 
var ctx = document.getElementById("pieChart");
var PieChart = new Chart(ctx,{
    type:'pie',
    data:{
        labels:['European Candadian','Chinese','South Asia','Fillipino','Southeast Asian','Japanese','Latin American','Mixed visible minority','Korean','Aboriginal','West Asian','Black','Arab'],
        datasets:[{
            label:"Ethnicity",
            data:[46.2,27.7,6,6,3,1.7,1.6,1.5,1.5,2,1.2,1,0.5],
            backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255,99,132,0.5)',
                    'rgba(155,130,32,0.5)',
                    'rgba(105,9,132,0.5)',
                    'rgba(15,130,202,0.5)',
                    'rgba(15,250,252,0.5)',
                    'rgba(205,100,32,0.5)',
                    'rgba(0,205,0,0.5)',
                    'rgba(55,15,52,0.5)',
                    'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)',
                    'rgba(25,59,52,0.5)',
                    'rgba(0,100,55,0.5)',
                    'rgba(200,231,50,0.5)',
                    'rgba(155,22,30,0.5)',
            ], 
            borderColor:[
                    'rgba(255,99,132,0.5)',
                    'rgba(155,130,32,0.5)',
                    'rgba(105,9,132,0.5)',
                    'rgba(15,130,202,0.5)',
                    'rgba(15,250,252,0.5)',
                    'rgba(205,100,32,0.5)',
                    'rgba(0,205,0,0.5)',
                    'rgba(55,15,52,0.5)',
                    'rgba(255,0,0,0.5)',
                    'rgba(25,59,52,0.5)',
                    'rgba(0,100,55,0.5)',
                    'rgba(200,231,50,0.5)',
                    'rgba(155,22,30,0.5)',
            ],
            borderWidth:[1]
        }],
        cutoutPercentage:[0]             
        
    },
    options:{
        title:{
            display:true,
            text:"Vancouver Ethnicity",
            fontSize:"20",
            fontColor:"rgba(20,20,20,1)"    
        },
    }
});

// Radar
Chart.defaults.scale.ticks.beginAtZero = true;

var ctx = document.getElementById("radarChart");
var RadarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type:'radar',
    data:{
        labels:['Hiking','Sporting Events','Stanley Park','Skiing & Snowboarding','Beaches','eating'],
        datasets:[{
            label:"Male",
            data:['50','70','80','60','20','70'],
            backgroundColor:[
                'rgba(255,155,32,0.5)',
            ],
            borderWidth:1,
            pointBackgroundColor:["yellow","black","green","white","skyblue","red"],
            pointHoverBackgroundColor:["black"],
            pointStyle:["triangle"]
        },
        {
            label:"Female",
            data:['60','30','80','20','50','60'],
            backgroundColor:[
                'rgba(155,15,132,0.5)',
            ],
            borderWidth:1,
            pointBackgroundColor:["yellow","black","green","white","skyblue","red"],
            pointHoverBackgroundColor:["black"],
            pointStyle:["triangle"]
        }
        ]
    },
    options:{
        title:{
        display:true,
        text:"Activities in Vancouver",
        fontSize:"20",
        fontColor:"rgba(10,0,20,0.9)"
        },
        legend:{
        display:false,
        position:'right',
        labels:{
            fontColor:'#000',
        }
            },
        scales:{
            scale: {
            }
        }
    }
});

// Select Options
var lineChart = document.getElementById("lineChart"),
    barChart = document.getElementById("barChart"),
    pieChart = document.getElementById("pieChart"),
    radarChart = document.getElementById("radarChart");

function myFunction(){
    var chartType = document.getElementById("chartType");
    var i = chartType.selectedIndex;
    if (chartType.options[i]) {
        lineChart.style.display = "inherit";
}
}
```

```html
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
   
   <div class="container">
        <h1><span>V</span>ancouver Census</h1>
        <!-- Vancouver Population -->
        <select id="chartType" onchange="myFunction()">
            <option value="line">Population</option>
            <option value="bar">Precipitation</option>
            <option value="pie">Ethnicity</option>
            <option value="radar">Activity</option>
        </select>
        <div class="chart_container" id="display">
            <canvas id="lineChart" style="display:none"></canvas>
            <canvas id="barChart" style="display:none"></canvas>
            <canvas id="pieChart" style="display:none"></canvas>
            <canvas id="radarChart" style="display:none"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What I am trying to achieve here is when I select the "population", the linechart shows up. And when I select "precipitation", barChart shows up. 
I am aware that I am missing some kind of logical functions. I tried with if statement by writing if (chartType.options[0]) {lineChart.style.display = "inherit"} but it ends up applying to all the options. I appreciate for tips and help.

Comment: You have to 1- hide the previously shown chart, 2- a `switch` case on the selected option text, 3- show the selected chart

Comment: Sorry I am not getting what you are suggesting..How do you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comment:

#### 1- Hide the previously shown chart

In order to do that, you have two things to do: find what chart is currently being displayed, and hide it.

Let's first add two classes: `hidden-chart` and `active-chart` and their CSS:

```
.hidden-chart { display: none !important; }
.active-chart { display: inherit !important; }
```

And edit the HTML accordingly:

```
<canvas id="lineChart" class="hidden-chart"></canvas>
<canvas id="barChart" class="hidden-chart"></canvas>
<canvas id="pieChart" class="hidden-chart"></canvas>
<canvas id="radarChart" class="hidden-chart"></canvas>
```

Okay, so now you can have two types of charts: hidden charts with the `hidden-chart` class and the currently being displayed chart with `active-chart` class.

In order to achieve 1), you'd now have to add the following code to your function:

```
function myFunction() {
    const currentChart = document.querySelector("#display .active-chart");
    if (currentChart) {
        currentChart.classList.remove("active-chart"); // Remove the active-chart class
        currentChart.classList.add("hidden-chart"); // Add the hidden-chart class thus hiding the chart
    }

    var chartType = document.getElementById("chartType");
    var i = chartType.selectedIndex;
    if (chartType.options[i]) {
        lineChart.style.display = "inherit";
    }
}
```

---

#### 2- A switch case on the selected option's text:

Well that is a quite trivial `switch`, on the HTMLElement.text variable:

```
function myFunction() {
    const currentChart = document.querySelector("#display .active-chart");
    if (currentChart) {
        currentChart.classList.remove("active-chart"); // Remove the active-chart class
        currentChart.classList.add("hidden-chart"); // Add the hidden-chart class thus hiding the chart
    }

    var chartType = document.getElementById("chartType");
    var i = chartType.selectedIndex;

    const selectedOption = chartType.options[i]; // The option the user has clicked on
    let toEnableChart;
    switch (selectedOption.text) {
        case 'Population':
            toEnableChart = lineChart;
            break;

        case 'Precipitation':
            toEnableChart = barChart;
            break;

        case 'Ethnicity':
            toEnableChart = pieChart;
            break;

        case 'Activity':
            toEnableChart = radarChart;
            break;
    }

    if (chartType.options[i]) {
        lineChart.style.display = "inherit";
    }
}
```

You could replace the switch with a standard if else if else if else construct.

---

#### 3- Enable the new chart

Now that we know what chart to display (`toEnableChart` variable, thanks to the switch ; and we know how to display it - remember our hidden-chart and active-chart classes?), it's time to display it!

```
function myFunction() {
    const currentChart = document.querySelector("#display .active-chart");
    if (currentChart) {
        currentChart.classList.remove("active-chart"); // Remove the active-chart class
        currentChart.classList.add("hidden-chart"); // Add the hidden-chart class thus hiding the chart
    }

    var chartType = document.getElementById("chartType");
    var i = chartType.selectedIndex;

    const selectedOption = chartType.options[i]; // The option the user has clicked on
    let toEnableChart;
    switch (selectedOption.text) {
        case 'Population':
            toEnableChart = lineChart;
            break;

        case 'Precipitation':
            toEnableChart = barChart;
            break;

        case 'Ethnicity':
            toEnableChart = pieChart;
            break;

        case 'Activity':
            toEnableChart = radarChart;
            break;
    }


    if (toEnableChart) {
        toEnableChart.classList.remove("hidden-chart");
        toEnableChart.classList.add("active-chart");
    }
```

As you may notice, displaying the new chart is step #1, but backwards.

---

Feel free to comment if something is unclear.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will take some time to read it through. Where do I put the "active-chart" class?

Comment: No worries. I've put the classes in a [<style>](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_style.asp) element. Don't forget to mark the answer as correct if it solved your issue. :)

Comment: I marked the answer because you put so much efforts into it. It hasn't completely solved the problem but it is working in a random way. For example, the default screen starts from every charts visible and then when I select ethnicity, the population also shows up...let me upload the codes on code fiddle.

Comment: Okay I know why. I put "active-chart" with "hidden-chart" in the class that is why they were being messed up. By the way, I already encountered various things I haven't used such as let, const, and classList...I gotta study what they are. Thank you so much again as this was my school project. I will definitely try to understand this on my own.

Comment: It's great you're motivated to understand what I've done. If you need any help feel free to comment on this thread or ask a new question! :)

Comment: Thanks! I will. May I ask you how long you have been studying coding?

Comment: I've been coding for the past five years as a hobby and the past two years as a 'real' student.

Comment: I see, that is awesome. I have been studying for 8 months now and I will work hard to get where you are :)